# I send email and receive error code

Tags: ios

I am sending message to a partner via email I keep receiving this,
"Remote host said: 550 #5.1.0 address rejected [RCPT_TO]"
I need advise, please.
Thank you.

Comment: Initial advice is to show how you're sending the e-mail (the code) and the full error output. Are you sure the address is actually valid?

Comment: Yes the email address is correct.

Comment: Yes the email address is currently valid.

Answer (score 0):

I know 3 cases in which server could answer like this

1. E-mail addres like that not exists or there is misprint in e-mail
2. Spam-filter is not accepting mail from your e-mail address (your address is marked like *spam sender*)
3. Problems with MX records on domain (if it's private e-mail server)

Knowing this options i recommend you to try this cases

1. Send from other e-mail address to check if the previous adrress is rejected by spam filter.(Maybe from other e-mail domain)
2. Send to another e-mail address on that server to check if it is a problem with server e-mail
3. If it is private server you should check problems with MX records([Use this tool like an option to check](http://mxtoolbox.com) or Send a letter to e-mail server admin with your issue)

Have a nice time and i hope your problem will be solved.